# Error creating bean with name 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have application `Java11` spring boot work find, and I try to add `OpenId` connect plug  for consume, I have error on my bean.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
...
    at com.BatchApplication.main(BatchListeBlancheApplication.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'oauth2SecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:223) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user(Model model,
                       @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
        model.addAttribute("userName", oidcUser.getName());
        model.addAttribute("audience", oidcUser.getAudience());
        return "user";
    }
}
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login((Customizer<ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2LoginSpec>) withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-name=client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-id=client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-secret=<key>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.redirect-uri=https://openidconnect.net/callback
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.scope=openid, profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.issuer-uri=https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.authorization-uri=https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.token-uri=https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/token
```

i try to change authorization_code to client_credentials

I tried to add a '/' at the end of issuer-ur and redirect-uri

I don't have access to parameter of server.

How do I get my OAuth client ?

configuration i received

```
/authorize

 https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/authorize?
 client_id=client
 &redirect_uri=https://yourdomain.net/callback
 &scope=openid
 &response_type=code
 &state=<string value>

/token

 POST https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/connect/token
 grant_type=authorization_code
 &client_id=client
 &client_secret=<string value>
 &redirect_uri=https://openidconnect.net/callback
 &code=<string value>
```

if a add this ligne of configurration
`spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.jwk-set-uri=https://myapp/AutoConnectSSO/idserver/.well-known/jwks`

```
o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ...
    at com.myapp.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:27) ~[classes/:na]

2022-07-18 14:39:48.643 ERROR 31468 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Parameter 0 of method springSecurityFilterChain in com.myapp.hexa.application.OAuth2SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' in your configuration.
```

Comment: use  jwk-set-uri it's good parameters,And `@EnableWebSecurity` need to by only on main class